# why nvcc doesn't work while cmake works when compiling a CUDA C++ project?

Tags: debugging, cmake, cuda, nvcc, libtorch

I have a code written in CUDA C++, I can build this project using CMake, Make and run it as usual. But when I try to use nvcc to debug it, it throws an error like

```
fatal error: ATen/ATen.h: No such file or directory
```

My CUDA version is:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Oct_12_20:09:46_PDT_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.1, V11.1.105
Build cuda_11.1.TC455_06.29190527_0
```

I have a server with 4 GPUs.
Is there any Idea what the problem may be?

I tried the following code:

```
nvcc -o test1 test.cu
```

All source files and header files (`.cu` files and `.h` files) are in one folder, `src`.
I build my project inside the folder `Build`, inside the project folder.
My `CMakeLists.txt` file contains the following code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project("test1")

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/data/extern/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch")
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS}")

include_directories(test1 PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src) #add header
include_directories("${TORCH_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES src/*.cu) #add all source files in the system
add_executable("${PROJECT_NAME}" ${SRC_FILES})
target_link_libraries(test1 ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(test1 "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
set_property(TARGET test1 PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
if (MSVC)
  file(GLOB TORCH_DLLS "${TORCH_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/*.dll")
  add_custom_command(TARGET test1 
                     POST_BUILD
                     COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
                     ${TORCH_DLLS}
                     $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:test1 >)
endif (MSVC)
```

Comment: why does your project name have a trailing space?

Comment: Use `make VERBOSE=1` to see how `nvcc` is called by the generated `Makefile`.

Answer (score 1):

... An error like

```
fatal error: ATen/ATen.h: No such file or directory
```

means the include path you use when writing the compilation command directly is probably different than the path used by the CMake-generated compilation command.

As @paleonix suggests, if you get Make to be verbose about what it does, by setting `VERBOSE=1` variable appropriately when running make, then you'll get a listing of all commands executed. Identify the command which fails, and compare the command-lines.

Also, next time, please provide more details about such failures, since I am partially speculating based only on the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, In fact, there are no more details about the error; it's just one line of the message that says "fatal error: ATen/ATen.h: No such file or directory".
I expected that my torch path is different from the one used by `nvcc`, thanks for your advice, it's helpful.

Comment: @Tony.sy: There are more details... CMake has cached variables and logs, and when you build - you can make the build verbose and get the specific commands being issued.